# auto hotkey script to convert backward to forward slashes

Tags: windows-7, unix, script, hotkeys

Though I'm Windows based, I do my web development work in a customized console that mimics much of Unix particularities. One of these is that it uses forward slashes for paths, instead of backwards. I'm looking for a way to be able to copy/paste from a path with backward slashes to a path with forward ones. Perhaps there's an auto hotkey script I could use for this?

Thanks for insights!

Comment: For further info: I followed this tutorial when setting-up the console in reference: http://www.kevwebdev.com/blog/in-search-of-a-better-windows-console-using-ansicon-console2-and-git-bash.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've got is a mess of hacks, one piled atop another, and trying to use an AutoHotkey script to translate paths is just going to make that even worse.

What you *need* is to rip out that nonsense and do a proper [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) install, which will give you a proper terminal emulator in mintty, and a proper Unix shell environment which has already had a lot of the work done to make it play nicely with Windows -- for example, there's a utility, `cygpath`, which is included by default with Cygwin, and which accurately translates paths in both directions.

I'm not sure why people seem lately to be so hot on Git Bash over Cygwin. Judging by the page you cite for the process you followed, installing Cygwin is actually *less* effort than piling up the hacks, and you get a better experience out of it.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the direction. In case anyone else comes across this in efforts for a better Windows environment for rails development, found [this](http://www.tiplite.com/how-to-install-rvm-on-windows-using-cygwin/) simple tutorial for the necessary packages to install with Cygwin in order to get RVM (ryby version manager) installed.

Comment: @isaac Glad to be of help. For Ruby development under Windows, I've found the sanest method to be running a Linux VM as my development environment; it's a bit more effort on the front end, but once I've got the VM up and running, and SSH configured for passphrase-less public key authentication so that Emacs can transparently edit files on the VM without prompting for a password, the couple of hours involved in configuring the VM very quickly pays for itself.